# ubuntuの通知領域に’エラー：BrokenCount> 0’が表示されています。

Tags: linux, ubuntu

インストールやアンインストールを適切に行えなかったようで、依存関係を良くない状態にしてしまったようです。

> エラーが発生しました。右クリックでパッケージマネージャーを実行するか、端末で何が問題か確認してください。エラーメッセージは次のとおりです。'エラー：BrokenCount> 0 'これは、インストールしたパッケージの依存性が満たせない状態です。

パッケージマネージャーでアップデートをしたところエラーで完了できませんでした。
どのような手順でエラーを回復したらいいですか

Answer (score 1):

多分、自己解決しました。

```
sudo apt-get -f upgrade
```

を実行すると以下のような表示は出ますが

> 以下のパッケージが自動でインストールされましたが、もう必要とされていません:   
>   libbaloocore4 libbaloofiles4 libbalooxapian4 libepub0 libkactivities-models1   libkidletime4
>   libnepomukcleaner4 libnepomukcore4abi1 libqmobipocket1 libzip2  
>   nepomuk-core-data nepomuk-core-runtime shared-desktop-ontologies
>   これを削除するには 'apt-get autoremove' を利用してください。 
>   アップグレード: 0 個、新規インストール: 0個、削除: 0 個、保留: 0 個。

`autoremove` で`libbaloocore4`最初のファイルを指定するだけでこの文は消せました。